# Get list of Windows users

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, user-accounts

I have the following instructions in my code.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher usersSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectCollection users = usersSearcher.Get();
```

It works fine on most machines. But in some cases the result (users) is empty. I failed to determine the reason. all three machine where it had happened are Windows 7 (Ultimate, Professional, Home Basic).

Is there any special conditions that causes this query to fail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `Winmgmt` service running on that Windows 7 machines?   Try from command line: `wmic path Win32_UserAccount get /value`. FYI, `Winmgmt` = Windows Management Instrumentation service name.

Comment: @JosefZ, thanks for advice. I checked if Winmgmt is running - it's running. I tried the wmic command and had got "No instance(s) avaible" as answer.

Comment: Are your comps joined in a domain? Then sorry, I have no chance to act a part in...

Comment: @JosefZ, no they are not joined. It is three independent comps

Comment: Do you see users using `control userpasswords2`?

Comment: @JosefZ, yes, I can see users

Comment: I am being at an idle end... I'd try even `wmic /namespace:\\ROOT\CIMV2  path Win32_UserAccount get /value`, although  `wmic wmiset get ASPScriptDefaultNamespace /value` should return `root\cimv2`